# Create and email PDF in Javascript Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, email, pdf

I am using JavaScript and HTML to built an Apache Cordova app for Android. I would like the user to click/tap a button that will then generate a PDF with the string that they just entered into a text field, then open an email to send the PDF attachment. The attachment does not need to be saved to the device, but can do if it is required before sending. Is this possible and if so is there any documentation or tutorials on how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to achieve that we need to add some inputs and get it's values, and a button that will fire the js. Which is pretty easy.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeHolder="Enter Your name" />
<input type="text" id="lname" placeHolder="Enter Your last name" />
<input type="text" id="hobby" placeHolder="Enter Your hobby" />
<input type="text" id="skills" placeHolder="Enter Your skills" />

<button id="btn">
   Get results
</button>
<!--values will be shown inside the div#content-->
<div id="content"></div>
```

Next is the JavaScript part where you will be displaying all of the input values inside the `div#content` with a `<p></p>` tag.

**JavaScript:**

```
function onload() {
  var input, btn, p, content, input_array;
  //grab the button by ID
  btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  //grab all inputs 
  input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  //grab the div by ID
  content = document.getElementById("content");
  // Add some 'Data' inside the variable so that you show
  // the user what he answered
  input_array = [
    "Name:",
    "Last name:",
    "Hobby:",
    "Skills:"
  ];
    //attach the click event listener to the button
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        //Using the for loop, we basically create 4 <p> elements inside
    //the div#content
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      p = content;
      // we display all of the input values within a <p> tag
      // with a class of 'testing' so that you cn change it later
      // on for styling it etc..
      // Then we add the array and input values inside the <p> tag
      p.innerHTML += "<p class='testing'>" + input_array[i] + " " + input[i].value + "</p>";
    }

  }, false);
}
//call the function
onload();
```

Now that you have displayed the values, you can do a lot of stuff. You can store all of what the user wrote into an array, do some cool animations and fade in the result.

To generate the results into a PDF format, you need to use this plugin that I have found on GitHub that supposedly says users can save the generated PDF.

***(Please note that I personally have not worked with this plug-in before so I give you no guarantees.)***

Link: [cordova-plugin-html2pdf](https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-html2pdf)

Follow the documentation there and everything should work well.

**Demo:** [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ray716/402tb5ow/)